# How get/set view options of a folder, not a window, in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'm a bit confused by folder view options in AppleScript. In AppleScript they seem to be properties of windows. However, Finder itself remembers view options by folder (as one would expect). For example, go to a folder in Finder, change its view options, go to a different folder, then use the menu item Go -> Go to Folder... to go directly back to the old folder and you will find the view options you changed have been remembered.

How can I directly get and set the view options that Finder has saved by folder in an Applescript? This information must be somewhere...

Comment: Take a look in the Finder's scripting dictionary for properties of a `Finder window`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Finder, a 'folder' is a graphical representation of a unix directory. It *is* a window, just a window that displays and manipulates files and directories in various formats and styles.

The Finder's AppleScript dictionary makes a distinction between `folders` and `Finder windows`, as follows:

- A 'folder' is a scripting object for a unix directory, allowing a scripter to add, remove, rename, delete, and do other file system actions.
- A 'Finder window' is a scripting object that sets the visual presentation of a given directory, allowing a scripter to set which directory is shown in the window, the type of view being used, the visibility of the toolbar and status bar, and normal window attributes like size, position and visibility.

If your goal is to manipulate the file system, use a folder object. If your goal is change the way a directory is presented to users, use a Finder window object. These are just different aspects of the potential workflow.